# File gets a full path of local source file as its name when uploaded using Java FTPClient

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

So i have a basic GUI application, where there is an option to upload image files to an ftp server. Everything works fine except one thing: the files are getting renamed during the upload. The new name of the file will be the full path of the directory, which contained the file.

So in my case, i have an image on the desktop: `C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\image.png`. When I select the file in the JfileChooser, the name is still just `image.png`. But when I click upload to FTP server, the file will be renamed to `C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\image.png`. So if I want to download that file, I have to use this path: `/home/user/users/xy/images/C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\image.png` in order to download it. Idk what causing this problem. I use `FTPClient.putFileToPath(file,path)` to upload the files, and it works fine, the files will be uploaded. I tried to copy a file from my machine to the ftp server with total commander, and this problem never occurred. I provided some code snippet, which does the uploading job.

```
uploadmenu.getUploadBtn().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(!uploadMenuValidate()){
           for(File f : img_container){
            try {
                //This still gives me the normal file name
                System.out.println(f.getName()); 
                
                ftp.putFileToPath(f, FtpClient.DEST_DIR+SQLData.APP_USERNAME+"/"+f);

                 
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
           popup.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
});
```

I have all the files in the `img_container` array that I selected in the `JFileChooser`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`File.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toString--) returns:

> Returns the pathname string of this abstract pathname

You want to use [`File.getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName--):

```
ftp.putFileToPath(f, FtpClient.DEST_DIR+SQLData.APP_USERNAME+"/"+f.getName());
```

Comment: Ahh, jesus, what a mistake... idk how i didn't see that... Anyways, thank you for helping me out!